# Menu transparente com mudança de cor ao mover o mouse

Tags: javascript, css3

Como faço o efeito do menu no topo aparecer transparente mostrando uma imagem e quando mover o mouse aparece uma barra com cor igual esse template.
Alguém poderia me dar uma dica?

Exemplo:
http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/

Answer (score 1):

Basta **colocar** ou **não** um `background-color` nas `divs`. Se vc não colocar um background na div, vai mostrar o que tem por debaixo dela. Pra colocar cor vc usa `background-color` (OU somente `background`), pra colocar imagem vc usa `background-image`.

Dá uma olhada nesta página e aprenda a usar fundos (`backgrounds`): https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Eu não entendi como que eu faço para quando ele subir a imagem até o topo ficar transparente e quando ele mover pra baixo ficar branco.

Comment: Então. Quando a janela está no topo da página (scroll), o elemento está sem fundo, e quando a página desce, é atribuído ao elemento um fundo branco.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @DavidSamm disse, basta não atribuir uma cor de fundo ao elemento alvo, e depois ao fazer scroll definir-lhe uma cor.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('menu'); // elemento alvo
var numPx = '250'; // Quantidade de pixels a contar do TOP até definir a cor

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY > numPx) {
     el.classList.add('mudaCor'); // adiciona classe "mudaCor"
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('mudaCor'); // remove classe "mudaCor"
    }
});
```

```css
html { 
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOce.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
.section{height:100vh;}

/* Define o menu */
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Nova classe a ser atribuída ao elemento com os estilos desejados */
.mudaCor{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
#menu .item{display:inline-block;padding:15px;}
#body-wrapper{margin-top:70px;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="item">Inicio</div>
    <div class="item">Sobre</div>
</div>
<div id="body-wrapper">
    <div class="section">Primeira Secção</div>
    <div class="section">Segunda Secção</div>
    <div class="section">Terceira Secção</div>
</div>
```

No entanto se precisares mesmo de adicionar uma cor de fundo por alguma razão ou preferência, podes utilizar uma cor [**rgba**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp) qualquer e remover-lhe a opacidade toda por completo. Mas **nota** que também vai ser preciso adicionar um [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) para sobrescrever a cor anteriormente aplicada.

```
#menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.mudaCor{
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Exemplo ao vivo: https://jsfiddle.net/2jkupaz4/

Answer (score 0):

Veja assim, criando um `ul.active` com background de cor diferente. Assim, você pode usar o método `addClass` e `removeClass` quando usar o *scroll*. Dê uma olhada se desta forma resolve pra você:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event){

  var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
  var breakpoint = 50;
  if (yOffset > breakpoint){
    $("nav ul").addClass('active');
  }else{
    $("nav ul").removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

```css
body{
 background:#eee;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
}
nav ul{
  margin-top: 0p;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1000;
  width:100%;
  color:#333;
  list-style:none;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
  font-size: 18px;
}
nav ul.active{
  background:#fff;
  color:#212121;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 30px;
}
section{
  padding:100px 50px 50px;
  line-height:140%;
}
p{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Jon Snow</li>
    <li>Jack Sparrow</li>
    <li>George Harrison</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer at libero nunc. Ut nec maximus leo, et tristique lacus. Praesent condimentum eleifend gravida. Phasellus pharetra finibus sapien, in ullamcorper orci imperdiet at. Phasellus vel arcu suscipit, pellentesque massa nec, tincidunt neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus tristique nunc nec finibus commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus mattis nec lorem sed sollicitudin. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec tristique, orci a feugiat vulputate, enim risus egestas mi, ac efficitur purus est placerat justo. Vestibulum ex erat, facilisis at quam quis, euismod vehicula magna. Aliquam faucibus laoreet sapien nec vulputate. Etiam a sapien sit amet risus fermentum vehicula eu et velit.
  </p>
 
</section>
```